# Bootstrap custom responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am trying to achieve a responsive design using Bootstrap.
Following image represent the requirements for Desktop and Mobile devices.

Any suggestion/code to achieve this requirement?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: suggestion - use bootstrap grid system.

Comment: Bootstrap grid system is a solid bet, but Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Have a go, return when stuck.

Comment: they provide ``grid``...go there and check the example

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap

- > Use [start](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)
- > Tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)
- > [Examples](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/06/12-time-saving-bootstrap-examples/)